# Configuration Management together with git-flow

Tags: 8, configuration, version-control

Using multiple branch/developers strategy for developing features causes some issues with built-in Drupal configuration management.

Our scenario is the following:

1. Create new feature and export config using drush
2. Commit changes and configuration into git
3. Move to another branch and start working in another feature
4. Export config using drush (also exports config from the features added in the previous branch)
5. Cannot move easily between branches as some content types are missing

What is the best way to use feature branches in a multiple developer team without creating this overhead?

Comment: Can you add some details about how does this question differs from [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/199206/39516)?

Comment: That question is about the features module; this question doesn't mention the features module, just feature branches